# TYPO3 condition Symfony Expression language on plugin

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

How can I write this old style typoscript condition in Symfony Expression language?

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_myext_myplugin|bla > 0]
```

Perhaps something like

```
[request.getQueryParams()['tx_myext_myplugin[bla]'] > 0]
```

but that is obvious not working.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with nested arrays, see: [TYPO3 Forge](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86915)

Comment: Thx, I guess I use the old way and will get another huge warning flood in the log then..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[(request.getQueryParams()['tx_myext_myplugin'])['bla'] > 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

In case it is generating an error inside log then you need to check like this.. (i.e. Unable to get an item on a non-array)

```
[request.getQueryParams() and
request.getQueryParams()['tx_myext_myplugin'] and
request.getQueryParams()['tx_myext_myplugin']['bla'] > 0]

//Typoscript Code

[end]
```

> && can also be used as conditional operator here

Answer (score 0):

The old style TypoScript condition `[globalVar = GP:tx_myext_myplugin|bla > 0]` can be written with new condition syntax like `[traverse(request.getQueryParams(), 'tx_myext_myplugin/bla') > 0]`.

Use `traverse` in combination with `getQueryParams` to [avoid errors in case a key in the parameter array is not defined](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Conditions/Index.html#request-getqueryparams).